# OpenLayers - vector layer not redrawing correctly when map zoom

Tags: openlayers-2

I am loading an external GeoJSON file into a vector layer as described in the doc.

I load it into the map normally:

```
geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "json/CS_Fr_St_General.json",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        })
    }); 

olmap.addLayer(geojson_layer);
```

When I zoom in or out, the old drawings of the geojson are not removed and the new one is added over it.

[image]

I suppose there is a setting in olmap that prevent the geojson to be refreshed/redrawn when zooming but I dont know how to fix it.

You can inspect the olmap and the geojson_layer in the debug tool from this address

- https://carto48dev.mels.gouv.qc.ca/Infogeo/test/window.html

Use `console.log(olmap)` or `console.log(geojson_layer)`